# Received weird request URL in my TOMCAT access logs

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, post, access-log

I have received some weird request URL in my TOMCAT access logs. which is
as follows:-

```
\x16\x03\x01\x01\"\x01" 200 40788
```

as clearly seen from above log, the server has given `200(success)` response to the client(the one who is accessing above URL from our server).

I am really concerned whether the hacker is trying to post some malicious `data` on the server?

above request is in which format? is it in hexadecimal?
how should I convert above request URL to text format so that I will get to know
which resource he is trying to access or on which URL he is trying to post?

Comment: That's probably not a question for stack overflow but you'll get a bit on information here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/162782/apache-strange-requests-in-logs/162792

Comment: thanx a lot! but i want more information!!!!

Comment: Well, you can try to post it on Info Sec but you'll probably get the same answer

Comment: ok, i will post the same question on security.stackexchange

Comment: i have received same answer https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/165609/received-weird-request-url-in-my-tomcat-access-logs